# Getting "unknown host" on hostname despite adding it to /etc/hosts

Tags: ubuntu, hosts

I have an Ubuntu server called crow:

```
$ hostname
crow
```

But when I try to ping it (from itself), I get unknown host:

```
$ ping crow
ping: unknown host crow
```

This is despite explicitly adding crow to /etc/hosts:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost crow
```

What am I doing wrong?

Additional info in response to comments:

The hosts line of /etc/nsswitch.conf looks like this:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
```

Comment: Have you rebooted/restarted networking services after making the edit to your `hosts` file?

Comment: Modification of hosts file doesn't require restart of network services.

Comment: What does the hosts line in /etc/nsswitch.conf look like?

Comment: where do you ping it, from the server itself or from another machine in the same lan?

Comment: I've edited to answer these questions

Comment: As reference I once had this problem since I by mistake "lost" the s in hosts (in nsswitch.conf). So a faulty nsswitch.conf can cause this problem as well...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check permissions on /etc/hosts and /etc/nsswitch.conf files. They should be world-readable.

Comment: Indeed, there should be no need for sudo in `sudo cat /etc/hosts`.

Comment: And what if they are already world readable, however you still can't ping localhost?